# named routes arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've started this question [Named route with nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370882/named-route-with-nested-resources), and it lead me to this new one.

I've a named route defined in my routes:

```
map.game    ':platform_name/:game_name', 
               :controller => :games, 
               :action => :index,
               :platform_name => /pc|ps2|ps3|wii|ds|psp|xbox360/
```

Ok, so it would expect 2 arguments, :platform_name and :game_name right?

But, this is what happens:

```
game_path(:platform_name => object.platform.search_name, :game_name => object.game.search_title)
```

I get:

```
game_url failed to generate from {:platform_name=>"xbox-360", :action=>"index", :game_name=>"jose-cuervo", :controller=>"games"}, expected: {:action=>"index", :controller=>"games"}, diff: {:platform_name=>"xbox-360", :game_name=>"jose-cuervo"}
```

he rejects my arguments...
whats the correct way to pass them?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isn't it because you have `:platform_name => "xbox-360` but in the named route you have `xbox360` ?